# Calcular edad con fecha de nacimiento MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

necesito calcular la edad de una persona a partir de su fecha de nacimiento, pero me esta haciendo mal el calculo, les doy un ejemplo.

Pepito nacio el 17-Diciembre-1997, en este momento pepito tiene 19 años, pero a mi en el calculo me muestra como si tuviera 20 años.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
//FECHA NACIMIENTO EN LA BASE DE DATOS
[Display(Name = "Fecha Nacimiento")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime fecha_nacimiento { get; set; }
//CALCULO DE LA EDAD
 [NotMapped]
 [Display(Name = "Edad")]
 public int edad { get { return DateTime.Now.Year - fecha_nacimiento.Year; } }
```

En mi base de datos la fecha se encuentra asi:

> 1997-12-17 00:00:00.000

Comment: Amigo en el { return DateTime.Now.Year - fecha_nacimiento.Year; } estoy haciendo el calculo, pero parece que no lo se hacer, porque me da mal el calculo por la cuestion del calculo de los meses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se requiere realizar una validación para saber la edad actual, primero se obtiene la diferencia en años, luego se compara contra la fecha actual y si es menor significa que no hay cumplido años, entonces, se resta un año para obtener la edad al día de hoy:

```
DateTime fechaNacimiento = new DateTime(1997, 12, 15);

DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
int edad = DateTime.Today.Year - fechaNacimiento.Year;

if (DateTime.Today < fechaNacimiento.AddYears(edad))
    --edad;
```

Aquí puedes ver la <kbd>[Demostración](http://rextester.com/SHCS95614)</kbd>

En tu caso, tu código quedaría así:

```
public int edad
{
    get
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
        int edad = DateTime.Today.Year - fecha_nacimiento.Year;

        if (DateTime.Today < fecha_nacimiento.AddYears(edad))
            return --edad;
        else
            return edad;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente amigo, pero sin embargo sigue mostrándome la edad mal, me dice que tiene 20, cabe aclarar que la fecha de mi pc esta bien

Comment: Justo por eso puse la demostración, ¿la pudiste revisar? Igual y se nos está pasando algo.

Comment: ya revise amigo y no se que esta pasando, me sigue mostrando 20 años, tengo en mi base de datos DateTime como tipo de dato

Comment: Lo que yo haría es hacer *debug*, pondría un *breakpoint* en esta línea `DateTime now = DateTime.Today;` y a partir de ahí iría paso a paso para revisar el por qué no te está respetando el cálculo.

Comment: @ByGroxD, Para que este código te funcione basta con cambiar la validación y el retorno de la edad de la siguiente forma. Primero se resta la edad y luego se retorna la variable:

`if (DateTime.Today < fechaNacimiento.AddYears(edad)) edad--;                
return edad;`

Answer (score 0):

les dejo un pequeño arreglo sobre el codigo del compañero anterior.
Espero que les ayude.

Un saludo.

```
 [Display(Name = "Edad")]
    public int Edad
    {
        get
        {
            int edad = DateTime.Today.Year - FechaDeNacimiento.Year;

            //si el mes es menor restamos un año directamente
            if (DateTime.Today.Month < FechaDeNacimiento.Month)
            {
                --edad;                
            }
            //sino preguntamos si estamos en el mismo mes, si es el mismo preguntamos si el dia de hoy es menor al de la fecha de nacimiento
            else if (DateTime.Today.Month == FechaDeNacimiento.Month && DateTime.Today.Day < FechaDeNacimiento.Day)
            {
                --edad;
            }

            return edad;
        }
    }
```